# If $p$ is a distribution, what is the meaning of the claim $\nabla p\in L^p(\Omega)^d$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal D(\Omega):=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$
- $q\ge 1$

I've seen the following Lemma (without a proof) in a paper and don't understand how I need to interpret it:

> Let $p\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ with $\nabla p\in L^q(\Omega)^d$ $\Rightarrow$ $p\in L_{\text{loc}}^q(\Omega)$.

By definition, $$\nabla p(\Phi)\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\Phi_i)\stackrel{\text{def}}=-\sum_{i=1}^dp\left(\frac{\partial\Phi_i}{\partial x_i}\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }\Phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)^d\;.\tag 1$$

---

I know that each $f\in\mathcal L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ can be identified with $\langle f\rangle\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)$, $$\langle f\rangle(\phi):=\langle\phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)\;.\tag 2$$ I understand that this identification is the meaning of $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)\subseteq\mathcal D'(\Omega)$. By $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $$\nabla\langle f\rangle(\Phi)=-\langle\nabla\cdot\Phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\Phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)^d\tag 3\;.$$

---

However, even with $(3)$, I'm not able to make sense of $\nabla p\in L^q(\Omega)^d$. So, what is meant?

[As a secondary question, where can I find a proof of the Lemma and does the Lemma even hold for $q=\infty$?]

Comment: A distribution $d$ being in $L^p$ means that there exists a function $f$ in $L^p$ such that for $g \in \mathcal{D}$, $d(g)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f g dx$.

Comment: The use of $p$ for both a function and for an index on an $L^p$ space is not helping anything...

Comment: @paulgarrett Sorry, I've replaced one $p$ by $q$. But Ian made the same mistake by using $d$ for both the space dimension and a distribution ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking what I said uses a space dimension of $1$ but the extension is clear.

Comment: @Ian I guess you mean that $p\in L^q_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ means that there is some $f\in L^q_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ with $p=\langle f\rangle$, right? I understand that, but I don't know how this generalizes in $\nabla p\in L^q(\Omega)^d$.

Comment: The same is true when you drop the "local" part. It is also true for vector-valued functions: a vector-valued function is in $L^p$ if its norm is in $L^p$. Equivalently, a vector-valued function is in $L^p$ if all its components are in $L^p$. In other words, the meaning of $\nabla p \in L^q(\Omega)^d$ has nothing to do with the fact that $\nabla p$ is the gradient of something. It would have the same meaning if $\nabla p$ were just some arbitrary vector-valued function.

Comment: @Ian Don't know why, but I still don't understand what you're trying to tell me, while everything you write is clear to me. Maybe $\nabla p\in L^q(\Omega)^d$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}=\langle f_i\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\left\{1,\ldots,d\right\}$$ for some $f\in L^q(\Omega)^d$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, the derivatives themselves are $L^q$, not their antiderivatives. That's why I said the meaning is the same for any vector valued function: the components of $\nabla p$ should all be $L^q$ functions.

Comment: @Ian I've edited my last comment. What do you say now?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Ian Pretty obvious. Don't know why I got stuck on that. Do you know a reference for a proof of the Lemma?

Comment: My guess would be that you can prove that $p \in L^q_{loc}$ by proving that integration against it gives a bounded linear functional on $C^\infty_c$ equipped with the $L^{q'}$ norm (where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{q'}=1$). Integration by parts might be fruitful for that.

Comment: @Ian If $p\in L_{\text{loc}}^2(Ω)$ with $\nabla p\in L^2(Ω)^d$, then $\nabla p$ is actually $\nabla\langle p\rangle$ and the condition for $\nabla p\in L^2(Ω)^d$ yields $$\nabla\langle p\rangle=\langle f\rangle$$ for some $f\in L^2(Ω)^d$. Since $p$ itself is a function (not a distribution), can we express $f$ in terms of $p$? We've got $$-\langle\frac{\partial ϕ}{\partial x_i},p\rangle_{L^2(Ω)}=\langle ϕ,f_i\rangle_{L^2(Ω)}$$ and hence $$\langle ϕ,\sum_{i=1}^df_i\rangle_{L^2(Ω)}+\langle\nabla\cdot ϕ,p\rangle_{L^2(Ω)}=0$$ for all $ϕ\in\mathcal D(Ω)$. But that's all I was able to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard notation: if $p \in \mathcal D ' (\Omega)$, then $\nabla p \in \mathcal D ' (\Omega, \Bbb R^d)$ is a *vector-valued* distribution (the terminology is misleading, because it suggests that a vector-valued distribution has vectors as values, which it does not; the term is quite natural, though, in that a vector-valued distribution is a distribution on a space of vector-valued test functions) given by $\langle \nabla p, \varPhi \rangle = - \langle p, \text{div } \varPhi \rangle$.

The definition is quite natural if you think about it for a moment: if $p$ is in fact a smooth function and $F$ a smooth vector-valued map with compact support (i.e. a vector-valued test function), then $\nabla p$ can be viewed as a vector of distributions, and its value on $F$ is (using $\partial _i$ for $\frac {\partial} {\partial x_i}$)

$$\langle \nabla p, F \rangle = \sum _i \langle (\partial_i p), F_i \rangle = \sum _i \int (\partial_i p) F_i = \sum _i \int \partial_i (p F_i) - \sum _i \int p \partial_i F_i = \\
\sum_i 0 - \int p \sum _i \partial_i F_i = - \int p \ \text{div} F = - \langle p, \text{div } F \rangle ,$$

where $\int \partial_i (p F_i) = 0$ because $pF_i$ has compact support in the variable $x_i$ (because $F$ has).

On the other hand, the space $L^q (\Omega)^d$ is the space of *vector-valued* Lebesgue $q$-integrable functions, i.e. $L^q (\Omega)^d = L^q (\Omega, \Bbb R^d) = \{ V : \Omega \to \Bbb R^d \text{ measurable } \mid \int _\Omega \| V \|^q < \infty \}$, with equality understood as equality almost everywhere (as usual with Lebesgue spaces).

With all this clarified, the notation $\nabla p \in L^q (\Omega) ^d$ means that $\nabla p$ is a vector-valued distribution on $\Bbb R^d$ such that there exist $V \in L^q (\Omega)^d$ with $\nabla p = V$. The equality makes sense because, as with usual distributions, the space $L^q (\Omega) ^d$ embeds naturally in $\mathcal D ' (\Omega, \Bbb R^d)$.